# SOPT na TDC Florianópolis

Tags: debate

O SOPT está patrocinando a The Developers Conference em Florianópolis, e eu tô aqui (desde quarta feira) representando nosso site. 
Até agora ninguém me xingou, então estamos bem!

Se alguém estiver na conferência, ou na cidade, e quiser aproveitar a chance rara de reclamar diretamente com um CM do Stack Exchange, basta falar comigo. É a sua hora de me dizer exatamente como o site ia ser muito melhor se todo mundo concordasse com você :-P

PS: Se alguém estiver particularmente indignado por eu não ter dado nenhum retorno no primeiro Estado da Pilha, é porque a conferência não tem wifi, e a do hotel não tá funcionando... Mas eu gostei muito do que li até agora.

Comment: "Até agora ninguém me xingou, então estamos bem!" O pior é que numa área de atuação como essa, é bem isso mesmo. Se você faz um bom trabalho ninguém comenta (mas qualquer deslize a galera fala mal). Pra não ficar pelo silêncio, deixa eu dizer aqui que  SOpt tem sido sensacional desde o começo. Eu só teria elogios a fazer sobre este stack se lhe encontrasse pessoalmente.

Comment: Gabe, você vai estar no TDC de São Paulo também? Vou ver se consigo aplicar umas duas ou três palestras lá.

Comment: @Renan Concordo. Realmente o bom trabalho que os olhos não vêem o coração não sente. Agora se o site estivesse com bugs e gente revoltada estaria todo mundo falando sobre o assunto.

Comment: @utluiz é muito provável. Estamos pensando em fazer um encontro do site antes da conferência, inclusive. Mas não tem como confirmar nada agora.

Comment: Mais uma coisa Gabe, conversando com meus colegas, a única reclamação que ouvi de alguns poucos sobre o SOPT, SO e até outros fóruns como o GUJ é de que eles ficaram de alguma forma intimidados por perguntarem da "forma errada" e terem a pergunta fechada ou negativada. Então eu expliquei a eles o intuito do site e como é difícil responder uma pergunta que não é bem formulada e eles concordaram que a atuação do pessoal foi até razoável.

Comment: Legal! Ah, antes que eu esqueça... bom trabalho! Parabéns pra vc e pra equipe do SO!

Comment: @utluiz uma coisa que tento passar as pessoas que trabalham comigo é que perguntar é uma habilidade como qualquer outra, e que você só aprende errando. Ainda faço um blog só pra escrever um texto sobre isso algum dia.

Comment: @utluiz e Renan, obrigado! Também estamos muito contentes com o site!

Comment: @Gabe Vai estar aqui em Floripa até domingo? Deixei para participar somente da trilha de arquitetura, se ainda estiver quero lhe dar os parabéns pessoalmente pela iniciativa. O SO está ótimo.

Comment: @Caputo domingo pela manhã eu ainda estou na na conferência! Mas tenho que ir na hora do almoço.

Comment: @Gabe Moro aqui nos Ingleses, Você está em algum stand? Domingo pela manhã vou dar-lhe os parabéns. Até lá

Comment: Que absurdo, não tem wifi na conferência?! Numa conferência de desenvolvedores?!! Nem no hotel?!!! A SE andou economizando na sua hospedagem, é? :)

Comment: @bfavaretto a SE andou economizando até nos estabilizadores, a julgar pela queda de ontem no site :D

Comment: @bfavaretto O TDC é uma conferência mais "simples" no sentido de que não tem uma infraetrutura grande. Até onde eu sei (pode ter mudado), ela funciona em grande parte com a ajuda voluntários para a organização e com parcerias para custear tudo. Em SP, a faculdade Anhanguera cede o local e só tem Internet porque ela deixa usar. A vantagem é que o preço é mais popular, 1/2 ou 1/3 do preço de uma conferência "top".

Comment: @Caputo tá na conferência?

Comment: @Gabe Estava sim, não sabia em qual estando procurar. Não tinha um stand do SO não é? E acabei nem olhando o celular.

Comment: @Gabe tens de mandar alguém a Portugal também :D

Comment: @utluiz O que eu disse era só provocação :) Mas legal ter essas informações sobre a TDC, sou bem desinformado em relação a conferências em geral. Capaz que eu me inscreva em algo na TDC de SP.

Comment: Não pude ir esse ano @Gabe mas ano que vem nos encontraremos certamente.